# Multiple Precompiled Assemblies of Same Name

Tags: unity, dll

I'm getting an error after I imported a package to Unity,

Multiple precompiled assemblies with the same name Newtonsoft.Json.dll included or the current platform. Only one assembly with the same name is allowed per platform. (Assets/Plugins/Newtonsoft Json/Runtime/AOT/Newtonsoft.Json.dll)

I looked around for a solution, and people were saying it had to do with Unity Ads(which I don't have) and another solution I found was to delete one of the Newtonsoft.Json.dll files, which, if I delete either or the app fails to build. I don't even know how to get rid of the package that's caused it, nor do I really want to, the issue started after I imported the package from this website,
https://readyplayer.me/

Does anyone know of any way to fix this? I really wish Unity would detect this errors on import, man, especially considering it was a Unity package. Or automatically ignore one of the assemblies lol

For reference, the other error is as follows,
Multiple precompiled assemblies with the same name Newtonsoft.Json.dll included or the current platform. Only one assembly with the same name is allowed per platform. (D:/VR-Chat/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@2.0.0/Runtime/Newtonsoft.Json.dll)
I'm not even sure why this is being imported with the package, but this one seems to be referenced in the manifest of the ReadyPlayerMe package.

I tried deleting one or the other, but it just creates issues with the relevant packages. When I deleted one it says my Java NDK is missing?

I thought this would fix the issue:

[image: Unticking NewtonSoft in the package import options]

But it turns out that unticking the box for the NewtonSoft asset just creates more issues: it says it can't find the NewtonSoft, and fails to build seemingly due to some NDK related error with the Webview asset of the package.

Also, I tested this on a completely empty project, the same issue occurs. There are two NewtonSoft Json files included, deleting either one of them does not get rid of the error, and deleting both allows it to successfully build on my empty project, but not on my main project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by deleting the two Newtonsoft files(there's one inside the folder as well)

The reason I hadn't tried this before was because I deleted one or the other and it didn't fix any of the errors(there was still 2 errors). I didn't think deleting both of them would fix it, but it did.